# TrialPay sending malformed JSON on callback

Tags: php, facebook, json

I am attempting to implement TrialPay/Offerwall/Dealspot on a Facebook app. In their [documentation](http://help.trialpay.com/credits/?p=545) they give an example of what the JSON looks like that they send you:

```
{"order_id":9006316682257,"buyer":409697,"app":107032282669135,"receiver":409697,
"amount":1,"time_placed":1322622026,"update_time":1322622027,"data":"",
"items":[{"item_id":"0","title":"3 Fred Currency","description":"Make it rain!",
"image_url":"http:\/\/external.ak.fbcdn.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQDldsPcWsejAJdC&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.etftrends.com\u00252Fwp-content\u00252Fuploads\u00252F2011\u00252F10\u00252Fcurrency-trading.jpg",
"product_url":"","price":1,"data":"{\"modified\":{\"product\":\"URL_TO_APP_CURR_WEBPAGE\",
\"product_title\":\"Fred Currency\",\"product_amount\":3,\"credits_amount\":1}}"}],"status":"placed"}
```

They say if you json_decode it as an array you should get this:

```
Array (
  [order_id] => 9006316682257
  [buyer] => 409697
  [app] => 107032282669135
  [receiver] => 409697
  [amount] => 1
  [time_placed] => 1322622026
  [update_time] => 1322622027
  [data] =>
  [items] => Array (
               [0] => Array (
                        [item_id] => 0
                        [title] => 3 Fred Currency
                        [description] => Make it rain!
                        [image_url] => http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDldsPcWsejAJdC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.etftrends.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2011%2F10%2Fcurrency-trading.jpg
                        [product_url] =>
                        [price] => 1
                        [data] => {"modified":{"product":"URL_TO_APP_CURR_WEBPAGE","product_title":"Fred Currency","product_amount":3,"credits_amount":1}}
                      )
             )
  [status] => placed
)
```

It doesn't though, data actually looks like this:

```
[data] => "{"modified":{"product":"URL_TO_APP_CURR_WEBPAGE","product_title":"Fred Currency","product_amount":3,"credits_amount":1}}"
```

The JSON being inside the string is causing it to be invalid JSON. Is there is a straightforward way to remove those quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer at [TrialPay](http://www.trialpay.com) here. We might have a typo in our doc sites, and I'll send a note around to double-check that.

In the meantime, I've verified that the actual JSON that Facebook is passing to the server-side callback on completion of an offer-based order for in-app currency should be valid, and decodes properly to the desired result above.

If you encounter any further problems outside the scope of this thread, feel free to ping me directly.

Edit:

After copying your code and validating against [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com), I encountered a problem right away at the point you mentioned. However, after removing the bad line break before `\"product_title\"`, I was able to validate correctly. Example PHP snippet included below:

```
<?php

$order_details = '{"order_id":9006316682257,"buyer":409697,"app":107032282669135,"receiver":409697,"amount":1,"time_placed":1322622026,"update_time":1322622027,"data":"","items":[{"item_id":"0","title":"3 Fred Currency","description":"Make it rain!","image_url":"http:\/\/external.ak.fbcdn.net\/safe_image.php?d=AQDldsPcWsejAJdC&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.etftrends.com\u00252Fwp-content\u00252Fuploads\u00252F2011\u00252F10\u00252Fcurrency-trading.jpg","product_url":"","price":1,"data":"{\"modified\":{\"product\":\"URL_TO_APP_CURR_WEBPAGE\",\"product_title\":\"Fred Currency\",\"product_amount\":3,\"credits_amount\":1}}"}],"status":"placed"}';
$order_details_decoded = json_decode($order_details, true);
$order_details_decoded['items'][0]['data'] = json_decode($order_details_decoded['items'][0]['data'], true);
print_r($order_details_decoded);
```

As I mentioned early, if anything else comes up outside the scope of this thread, feel free to ping me directly.

Comment: Thanks Rob, looking at the response sent to me by FB compared to yours it appears that mine has additional backslashes that yours does not. Do you have a preferred method of contact if I wanted to send you a specific example?

Answer (score 2):

First off, it looks like you need to finish configuring your app on Trialpay's site, hence the `URL_TO_APP_CURR_WEBPAGE`.  The issue here may be that you have not completed your app configuration to the extent needed to *produce* valid JSON.

If that's not the answer however, if you still get invalid JSON (which I agree, that's invalid) I would suggest contacting your Trialpay representative.  They're usually pretty responsive and we did unearth a few issues w/ their product during our game development.

Good luck - post back here if/when you find more info.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `json_decode($json_string, true);` that will convert it into an associative array.

Comment: json_decode isn't going to help if the JSON is invalid (and per the op's post, it is)

Comment: My mistake I thought he was just missing the array flag and was getting an object but expecting an array.